# C#. Queue<T> vs List<T>

Tags: c#, list, очередь

Является ли Queue более быстродейственым, чем List,  если List используется в формате FIFO?

Или разница только в строках кода...

P.S. Пример кода:

Случай А:

```
var list = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            // работа с list[i]

            if (BOOL) //BOOL в 90% случаев = true
            {
                list.RemoveAt(i--);
            }
        }
```

Случай B:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
        queue.Enqueue(1); queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(3); queue.Enqueue(4);
        queue.Enqueue(5); queue.Enqueue(6);
        queue.Enqueue(7); queue.Enqueue(8);
        queue.Enqueue(9);

        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Count; i++)
        {
            var integer = queue.Dequeue();
            // работа с integer

            if (!BOOL) //BOOL в 90% случаев = true (Инвертировано)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(integer);
            }
        }
```

Случай С:

```
var list = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        // работа с list[i]

        if (BOOL) //BOOL в 90% случаев = true
        {
            //Обработать как то иначе текущий list[i]...
        }
    }
```

P.P.S. Случай с "Обработать как то иначе" и Queue описывать не стал

Comment: Не знаю про C#, но обычно подразумевается, что Queue имеет определённый размер, поэтому доступ к любому элементу O(1), в отличие от списка с O(n).

Comment: А как вы собираетесь организовать работу `List<T>` по принципу FIFO? "Из коробки" такой функциональности у него нет. При большом желании это можно сэмулировать, но не очень понятен смысл подобных колдунств

Comment: Смысл в том что посредством for перебирается list, при определенном условии элемент удаляется. По сути на данном этапе он выполняет функцию FIFO. Будет ли выигрыш в скорости если заминить это на Queue?

Comment: P. S. Количество элементов заранее не известно.

Comment: Foggy Finder, Alexander Petrov, спасибо за комментарии. Видимо не совсем ясно что я имел ввиду. Описал пример в вопросе.

Comment: @0andriy, List - это не список, а вектор.

Comment: @Qwertiy, как несведущий человек, я пошёл читать официальную документацию https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx,  Слова vector я там не нашёл ни разу, что впрочем соответствует моей картине мира. Иначе зачем называть иную сущность так же?

Comment: @Opossum, если ваша очередь изменяет размер, то это не очередь. По определению.

Comment: @0andriy, я почему-то подумал, что большинство знает плюсы. В общем, я имел в виду, что [List в C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) является не связным списком, а массивом переменной длины так же как [std::vector в С++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: @Qwertiy, я конечно понимаю, что взгляд MS на привычные вещи может несколько отличаться, но по той же ссылке я увидел такое в частности: Capacity. Насколько я помню std::vector не имеет формальных ограничений на размер.

Comment: @0andriy, [c++ vector capacity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) & [C# list capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) - в чём разница? Кроме того, что при создании нового экземпляра у вектора указывается размер, а у list'а - вместительность? Это не ограничение на размер, а текущий размер буфера.

Comment: Вы про List, а я про Queue, и я запутался. Короче говоря, отличие List от Queue в получается лишь в способе доступа к данным. Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Короткий ответ - в вашей задаче Queue будет работать быстрее.

**Немного информации**

Что Queue, что List это коллекции, которые построены на массиве. Отличие в реализации - Queue содержит два указателя на голову и на хвост, которые актуализируются при Enqueue/Dequeue. Так что оптимизации компилятора, а также преимущества кеша процессора будут идентичны.

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то в ней происходит частый вызов RemoveAt\Dequeue. И тут различия огромные, т.к. каждый раз вызывая List.RemoveAt вы **копируете все элементы правее удаляемого** на новую позицию. Вызов Dequeue не проводит дорогостоящего копирования, а только уменьшает указатель на голову очереди.

Comment: Как я понял A и С по времени одинаковы

Comment: Ой, пардонте, B (Та что с очередью) и С (та что с доп обработкой)

Comment: При условии что код обработки и код "// работа с .." будет одинаковый

Comment: Да, практически одинаковый. Если еще Dequeue + Enqueue заменить на Peek - то вообще одинаковый.

Answer (score 1):

Да очередь будет быстрее, т. к. не надо двигать хвост.

А код из вопроса вообще не похож на FIFO, к тому же работает по-разному (во втором баг).
Правильно было бы просто создать ещё один список.

Comment: По факту у меня сейчас реализован "Случай С"

Comment: Баг тут? for (int i = 0; i < queue.Count; i++) ... queue.Enqueue(integer); ?

Comment: Значит два бага... Или ноль... Наверное.

Comment: Эм... Запутался.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос касается выделиня памяти и именно его следует считать как за операцию, которая выполняется дольше всего и именно её мы хотим оптимизировать, то прислушайтесь к ответу @panchenko.dm .

Но **обычно** проблема обстоит в других местах например:

1. обращение к файлам
2. сетевым ресурсам
3. неоптимальным запросам к базам данных
4. аллокации памяти под большие объекты (large object heap)
5. неоптимальных алгоритмов решающих задачу

Обязательно проверяйте свои решения при помощи нагрузочного тестирования, 
бенчмарков, например [benchmarkdotnet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/Overview.htm), или в самом простом случае при помощи класса [stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Лично я бы уделил больше внимания коду и его оформлению:

```
foreach (var item in list) 
{
    // ваша преобработка
}

foreach (var item in list.Where(x => ShoudBeProceed(x))) // метод определяющий необходимость пост обработки 
{
    // ваша постобработка
}
```

Согласитесь этот код выглядет более лаконично и его проще поддерживать так как его [цикломатическая сложность](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) ниже.